# Create Dynamic Fragments in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm building camera app which is similar to Instagram camera. You can add text and draw lines etc. For these functionalities I need different layout for each function. So, I'm using fragments to change view within activity. Now I want to change the top and bottom view and center view remain same always. Below are two images first one is activity view and second one is fragment view. In activity view there are three things top view, bottom view and center view. In fragment view there are only two things top and bottom view. There is no center view in fragment so I want to show activity center view in fragment. But problem is that when I run fragment it hide the whole activity view. Is there any way to make fragment center view transparent so I show up activity center view ?

[image: Activity View]
[image: Fragment View]

After run fragment the result is same as image 2. But I want something like Instagram Below are two images where top and bottom view changed but center view remain always same. When you click on pencil button layout change but the center view which is `ImageView` remain same.

[image: Capture Picture]
[image: Draw Line]

Answer (score 0):

You could try replacing only part of layout, first by giving id to layout containing only topView and bottomView, for example doubleView.
Then when you use FragmentTransaction, you can replace this View with new Fragment, for example:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.doubleView, new SampleFragment(), "someTag");<br>
ft.addToBackStack(null);<br>
ft.commit();
```

Hope it helps! :)